# animate Textbox Content from "Hello" to nothing

Tags: c#, wpf

so i am playing with C# WPF Animations a little. And i need help.
I understand how to animate values like colors, width, position etc.

But i dont get it how to change content in a animation. I want to Fade out the Textbox Content on Focusing the Textbox. I dont find the Storyboard.setTargetProperty(changeContent?) for Text content.

Here my code thsi animates the width:

```
        private void onGotFocusLoginID(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

            if(txtLoginID.Text.Equals("deineMail@mail.de")) {
                DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
                doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3, 0));
                Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
                storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, txtLoginID);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty));
                doubleAnimation.To = 500;
                storyBoard.Begin();

                txtLoginID.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

I tried it with changing the foreground color to transparent, but the text is still there.

I also tried it with a label before the textbox, it works good but i cant click through the label. You know?

Answer (score 0):

To fade out the `TextBox.Text` you should animate the `Brush.Opacity` property of the `TextBox.Foreground` brush.

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, myTextBox);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Foreground.Opacity"));
```

If your goal is to create a watermark `TextBox`, where the placeholder disappears when the `TextBox` receives keyboard focus, you should override the `ControlTemplate` of the `TextBox`.
Simply overlay the text host (inside the template) with a`TextBlock` that holds the placeholder text. Then animate the `TextBlock.Opacity` property for a fade in/out effect:

```xml
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <Grid>

                <!-- Mandatory presenter for the Text property -->
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />

                <!-- The overlay placeholder text presenter -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="WatermarkHost"
                           Text="deineMail@mail.de"
                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                           Opacity="0" />
              </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="Text"
                             Value="" />
                  <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                             Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WatermarkHost"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       To="1"
                                       Duration="0:0:2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WatermarkHost"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       To="0"
                                       Duration="0:0:2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
              </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: i know it's been a while but i did not have access to my account.
Thanks for that!